# (Vowpal Wabbit) cb mode in contextual bandit problem

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have two quick questions about the use of contextual bandit mode in Vowpal Wabbit.

1) Does `--cb` mode output a deterministic policy, which greedily chooses the best action learned by a given training dataset? Thus, the probability of choosing the action is 1, and 0 for all the others.

2) I wonder which theoretical background is behind the policy learning process of `--cb_explore`. I know the policy learning process of `-cb` is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4601.pdf. Does `--cb_explore` use the same process? Since `--cb_explore` is basically a non-stationary policy, I think it should use a different process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Quick answers:**

1. Fundamentally yes, given a *certain context*, the action with the best (known) reward wins. However note that learning with `--cb` also supports `--epsilon <portion>` (***epsilon-greedy*** algorithm for exploration). During first-time learning, some portion of the action-space is used for further exploration (as opposed to pure greedy exploitation of what is already known).
2. Multiple exploration-vs-exploitation algorithms and some further hyper-parameters per algorithm are supported, depending on command line options

### A more detailed answer sourced from [vowpalwabbit.org](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/contextual_bandits.html)

Note: *vowpalwabbit.org* is an excellent resource for further information on contextual-bandits in `vw`.

> **Vowpal Wabbit supports three (3) contextual bandit base-algorithms:**

1. `--cb` The contextual bandit module which allows you to optimize predictor based on already collected data, or contextual bandits without exploration.
2. `--cb_explore` The contextual bandit learning algorithm for when the maximum number of actions is known ahead of time and semantics of actions stays the same across examples.
3. `--cb_explore_adf` The contextual bandit learning algorithm for when the set of actions changes over time or you have rich information for each action. Vowpal Wabbit offers different input formats for contextual bandits.

> **When exploration is in effect, Vowpal Wabbit offers five (5) exploration algorithms:**

- Explore-First: `--first`
- Epsilon-Greedy: `--epsilon`
- Bagging Explorer: `--bag`
- Online Cover: `--cover`
- Softmax Explorer: `--softmax` (only supported for `--cb_explore_adf`)

> **Working examples which include:**

- full command line
- input data
- expected output

for every option, can be found in the source tree in the file [tests/RunTests](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/test/RunTests) scroll down to the `__DATA__` section to find many command examples.

Comment: What is the baseline learner for —cb? Each call to vw.learn() has to take some F(context, action) = Reward and the action that gives biggest reward is choosen for recommendation. But during training what is the “F” defaulted to (linear, neural net, tree, etc...)?